# Symfony 1.4 Form validation without doctrine

Tags: forms, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this form:

form action="...." method="get"

Zip Code: input type="text" name="location"

I would like to validate that the zip code's length is five and that they are all numbers.

I'm stuck on how/where to do this without creating a doctrine form and running sfValidators through the configure() function.

I found some documentation to do this in 1.2, but it seems that it has been removed in 1.4.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's essentially the same as 1.4 as 1.2. You don't need to create an instance of sfDoctrineForm, just sfForm:

```
class MyForm extends BaseForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->setWidget('zip_code', new sfWidgetFormInputText(array(), array('size' => 5, 'maxlength' => 5));
    $this->setValidator('zip_code', new sfValidatorInteger(array('min' => 0, 'max' => 99999));
  }
}
```

You would then bind the form and use sfForm::getValues() to retrieve the bound values.

Comment: Jeremy - Not quite sure what you mean... I have the form in a template. How do I tie it all together?? I'm still a Symfony novice, and I appreciate your patience. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you creating the form? That should happen in an action, so should the processing of the form. Can you paste your code or explain more about what you're doing?

Comment: I wrote the code in plain html in the template. Then the action uses the post parameters:      if($request->getParameter('location') && $request->getParameter('breed')):
   $location = $request->getParameter('location');
   $this->location = $request->getParameter('location');
   $this->breed = $request->getParameter('breed');
   $this->id = $request->getParameter('id');

Comment: That's not the way to do something like this in Symfony. You should use the form framework.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't expect a sfValidatorInteger here, so in Germany zip-codes may also start with a 0 (like "08122") - or whatever all over the world :-)

Take a sfValidatorRegex with "[0-9]+" or sth on your needs !

Comment: Please, make this a comment on jeremy's question or edit his. This is not a complete answer.